# How to get Yarn application log in Python

Tags: python, hadoop-yarn

I want to get the yarn application log in python, I know in cmd it can simply be done by "**yarn logs -applicationId ${application ID}**", but how to do this in python code if I already have the application ID?
I tried yarn_api_client so far, but can only get the application info, not the logs. Here's my code:

```
from yarn_api_client import ResourceManager
list = []
list.append("http://my_cluster_url/cluster")
resource_manager = ResourceManager(list)
info = resource_manager.cluster_application("my_application_id")
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I see that there's a `amContainerLogs` field in the JSON that is returned describing an application.  That field contains a URL.  I wonder if that might get you the data you're interested in. - forgive me if I'm looking at something that doesn't apply to your situation.

Comment: @Steve yeah, that's driver's log, but how can I get executer's log? Thanks in advance